# Log all mysql queries without tampering code

Tags: php, debugging

Is there a way, to log all the mysql queries, like xhprof does with function calls - without tampering with the code? Are there any PHP extensions for this job?

I want a page execution based log of queries, not MySQL's logging facility.

Comment: Do you mean just the actual query (i.e. `UPDATE ...`), or are you thinking of a more comprehensive log dump, such as query results, records affected, server load at the time of query, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused as to what you are trying to achieve here - or not explaining it well.

What have you tried?

What do intend to do with the information?

What does `I want a page execution based log of queries, not MySQL's logging facility` mean?

There's at least 3 way's I can think of acheiving it.

- Use the [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) to wrap the relevant functions / methods with a logging layer
- use mysql logging (slow query / general / replication)
- route the conections via [mysqlproxy](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/databases/2007/07/12/getting-started-with-mysql-proxy.html) and log the requests there.

Comment: Given a fairly big project running in development environment. I want to log what queries does a specific page request initiates. I want it separated, page by page, not an en masse of mysql queries in a log file. Btw, I take a look at runkit.